# How do I add text to this PHP function?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to add text to this code for writing the sites description. If the title is empty it writes a default description. If not it writes `$title`.

I want to add text before `$title`

```
<?php echo isset($title) ? _h($title) : config('blog.description') ?>
```

At the moment you would get:

> Title of this story

I would like

> An article about: Title of story

Answer (score 6):

It is PHP basics. Have a look at this doc's page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
<?php echo 'An article about: ' . (isset($title) ? _h($title) : config('blog.description')); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This adds the 'An article about:' to both conditions though. I only want to to add it when there is a $title.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the requirements. The way you did it is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo isset($title) ? config('blog.leader') . _h($title) : config('blog.description') ?>
```

This was the solution I used. The leader only appears when $title is in use and can be configured externally.